# How to get Custom Metadata Type PickList field values using LWC getPicklistValues and getObjectInfo

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-metadata, getobjectinfo, getpicklistvalues

I'd like to access the picklist values of a field on a `Custom Metadata Type` from an `LWC`:

```
import { getPicklistValues } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
import { getObjectInfo } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
import SYNC_MODE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Setting__mdt.Sync_Mode__c";
import SETTING_MDT_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Setting__mdt";
```

Then I am using `getObjectInfo`

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: SETTING_MDT_OBJECT }) 
settingObjectInfo
```

And then I am using `getPicklistValues`

```
@wire(getPicklistValues, { 
                            recordTypeId: "$settingObjectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId", 
                            fieldApiName: SYNC_MODE_FIELD 
                          }) 
syncModes;
```

But both `settingObjectInfo` and `syncModes` are `null`

Am I correct in assuming that `getObjectInfo` and `getPicklistValues` don't support `Custom Metadata Type`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the documentation here could use some clarification.

1. This reference appears to leave open the possibility that Custom Metadata types may be supported by lightning/ui*Api modules (however, MDT's are not really "custom objects," strictly speaking):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_supported_objects

> The wire adapters and JavaScript functions in lightning/ui*Api modules
> are built on User Interface API. User Interface API supports all
> custom objects and many standard objects.

2. When it comes to the Lightning Data Service overall, the documentation is clear -  Custom Metadata Types are not supported:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/data_guidelines

> IMPORTANT Lightning Data Service supports all custom objects and all
> the standard objects that User Interface API supports. External
> objects, person accounts, and custom metadata types are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

First off you can import both in one line as per below. :)

```js
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
```

Also, as per below link it does not explicitly say it supports Custom Meta Data. User Interface API supports all custom objects and many standard objects.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_supported_objects